# OBIEE Time Difference between two columns

Tags: oracle, timestamp, obiee

Can anyone help me as to why this formula isn't working? 
I have two columns, Time Start and Time Finish, I want to find the difference in hours between them.

```
cast(floor(mod(TIMESTAMPDIFF(sql_tsi_second, "Worker"."Time Normal Finish","Worker"."Time Normal Start"),3600) /60)as char)
```

I am getting the error as such:

```
Formula syntax is invalid.
[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 22025] Function TimestampDiff is called with an incompatible type. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT cast( floor( mod(TIMESTAMPDIFF(sql_tsi_second, "Worker"."Time Normal Finish","Worker"."Time Normal Start"),3600) /60) as char) FROM "Workforce Management - Absence Real Time"
OK (Ignore Error)
```

**UPDATE**:
The two columns are plain text format, but i need to find the difference between them: 
Eg: 17:00-9:00=8 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to cast your columns before you can run the TIMESTAMPDIFF? That's what the error says: you have an incompatible type. You need to do TIMESTAMPDIFF(sql_tsi_second, cast( ...), cast(...)). Hope this works!

Comment: Exactly. You can't expect to do a TIME operation on a STRING.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer by @m-beerden is correct, in that you can't pass a string to timestampdiff. You need to convert it to a proper date-time format first.

There are a few other issues with your formula though. By passing the finish time as the argument before the start time, `TIMESTAMPDIFF` will return a negative number. If the times were exactly 8 hours apart this would be -28800.

Next you are performing a `MOD` on this, with 3600. `MOD( 28800, 3600 )` will return 0. If you really want the number of hours, you can use SQL_TSI_HOUR or you need to divide by 3600, not mod by it.